# Converting string into CLI instruction

Tags: bash

I have a the following in a bash script:

```
cmd="composer install"
`"$cmd"`
```

which results in:

> composer install: command not found

However if I just run this in the same bash script instead:

```
composer install
```

it work without issue. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't quote this variable expansion:

```
cmd="composer install"
$cmd
```

The variable is expanded, and because it's not quoted, the shell will proceed to split it up into words, so you do execute: "composer" "install" (instead of "composer install" as a single word)

---

Don't wrap it in backticks. This is wrong:

```
`$cmd`
```

That will execute the composer command, capture the stdout and then *try to execute the output as a command*.

---

One habit to get into is using bash arrays to build up commands. This is required because it's impossible for the shell to properly evaluate commands held in a single string when the command has arguments with whitespace. A fictitious example

```
cmd="composer install --users='fred barney'"
```

In this case    $cmd will expand into **4** arguments, not the 3 you'd probably expect:

```
"composer" "install" "--users='fred" "barney'"
```

If this may affect you, arrays are the way to go:

```
cmd=( composer install --users='fred barney' )
```

This array has 3 elements. The way to execute that is thus (ugly but correct):

```
"${cmd[@]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use functions instead:

```
#!/bin/bash

function special_command {
  composer install
}

special_command
```

You can also pass variables this way:

```
#!/bin/bash

function special_ls {
  ls -ld $1
}
function normal_ls {
  ls $file
}

special_ls /var/tmp

file=/var/tmp
normal_ls
```